# Error: Page contains property "price" which is not part of the schema

Tags: schema.org, google-search-console, rich-snippets

I've added some rich snippets to a product page on one of our client websites:

```
<div class="osetDesc" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div class="osetBikesImg">
        <img itemprop="image" src="images/oset/oset-12-5-eco_1.jpg" alt="OSET 12.5 ECO" class="largeImg" id="largeImg1" />
        <div class="osetSmall">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="thumb1"><img src="images/oset/oset-12-5-eco_1.jpg" alt="OSET 12.5 ECO" class="smallImg" /></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="thumb1"><img src="images/oset/oset-12-5-eco_2.jpg" alt="OSET 12.5 ECO" class="smallImg" /></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="thumb1"><img src="images/oset/oset-12-5-eco_3.jpg" alt="OSET 12.5 ECO" class="smallImg" /></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="thumb1"><img src="images/oset/oset-12-5-eco_4.jpg" alt="OSET 12.5 ECO" class="smallImg" /></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="thumb1"><img src="images/oset/oset-12-5-eco_5.jpg" alt="OSET 12.5 ECO" class="smallImg" /></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="thumb1"><img src="images/oset/oset-12-5-eco_6.jpg" alt="OSET 12.5 ECO" class="smallImg" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="osetText">
        <h2 itemprop="name">OSET 12.5 ECO <span>£<b itemprop="price">799</b></span></h2>
        <div itemprop="description">
            <p>The OSET 12.5 Eco is simple, sturdy, adjustable and easy to manage for riders from 2-5 years. A twist of the 'parent adjustable' speed dial allows the bike to grow with the child as their skills improve. What age to start? Some children can concentrate well enough at the age of 2. In any scenario, the OSET 12.5 can suit their needs.</p>
            <p>With the speed dial set to walking pace, the parent can follow the rider with a firm hand on the rear mudguard and assist as the child learns throttle control and balance. The OSET 12.5 is light, which allows 3 year olds to pick up their own bike after a spill!</p>
            <p>The 12.5 features front and rear suspension, reach adjustable brake levers, a full coverage chain guard, custom foot pegs for little feet and a first rate reliability record. Cost of ownership is very low, and re-sale value very high.</p>
            <p>In 2009 the OSET 12.5 was voted 'Product of the Year' by Dirt Rider Magazine. Quite an accolade - from the world's biggest MX magazine!</p>
            <ul class="osetUL">
                <li class="tech">Technical Specifications</li>
                <li>Wheelbase       <span>712mm</span></li>
                <li>Seat Height     <span>381mm</span></li>
                <li>Weight          <span>21kg</span></li>
                <li>Age Range       <span>2&ndash;5 yrs old</span></li>
                <li>Power           <span>500w, 24v</span></li>
                <li>Brakes          <span>Mechanical</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="contact">
            <span id="contactus">contact us</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

I'm receiving the error "Error: Page contains property "price" which is not part of the schema" when testing this in Webmaster Tools. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction of where I'm going wrong?

Thanks,

Liam

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For [`http://schema.org/Product`](http://schema.org/Product), there is no property named `price`.

You probably want to use [`http://schema.org/Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer), which has the [`price` property](http://schema.org/price).

Simple example:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <div itemprop="name">Product name</div>

  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <span itemprop="price">99</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @unor. I've managed to get to grips with Schema now and it's all pretty logical! :)